# Extract genres into a list from a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `dataframe` which looks like this -

```
id  genres
1   [{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]
2   [{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}, {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}]
3   [{'id':31, 'name':'Romance'}]
```

I want to extract genres from each of the `row` and store them in a `list`. For example -

```
id  genres
1   ['Comedy']
2   ['Comedy','Drama','Family','Romance']
3   ['Romance']
```

I tried this- 
`[j['name'] for i in data['genres'] for j in i]`
but it wrote all rows into a single list.

Answer (score 3):

Using `apply`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"genres": [[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}],[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}, {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}],[{'id':31, 'name':'Comedy'}]]})
df["genres"] = df["genres"].apply(lambda x: [i["name"] for i in x])
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                             genres
0                          [Comedy]
1  [Comedy, Drama, Family, Romance]
2                          [Comedy]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use nested list comprehension:

```
data['genres'] = [[j['name'] for j in i] for i in data['genres']]
```

For more general solution is better `get` - not failed, if not exist `name` key, but return `None` or another specified value:

```
data['genres'] = [[j.get('name') for j in i] for i in data['genres']]

data['genres'] = [[j.get('name', 'missing') for j in i] for i in data['genres']]
```

---

```
print (data)
   id                            genres
0   1                          [Comedy]
1   2  [Comedy, Drama, Family, Romance]
2   3                         [Romance]
```

Answer (score 0):

Also another possible method could be using apply():

```
df['genres'] = df['genres'].apply(lambda x: [d.get('name') for d in x])
```